# Combining Dense_Rank() and Lag() in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, dense-rank

I am generating Attempt Numbers based on `User ID`, `Topic ID`, `Item ID` and `Status`.

Unfortunately, the function `dense_rank()` does not fully do what I want it to do; to get full requirements I want to do the following:

(1) Create a view using `dense_rank()` to add attempt number where `status` = `started`. This will leave out other status' as `NULL`.

(2) Update the `NULL` values with previous Attempt Number values using `LAG()` function.

I managed to do step (1), however, I am struggling to find a clean way to do step (2).

This is my code:

```
CREATE VIEW [StartedRank] AS
SELECT createdAt, USER_ID, Topic_ID, item_id, [status],
    CASE
        WHEN [status] = 'started' then 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID, Topic_ID, item_id, [status] order by createdAt) 
        ELSE NULL
    END As AttemptNo
FROM [CurioTest].[dbo].[userprogressesv5]
WHERE type = 'practice' and user_id = '255251'
ORDER by createdAt
```

This will generate this table:

[image]

I then attempt to use this code to update the table:

```
UPDATE StartedRank
SET AttemptNo = LAG(AttemptNo, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_ID, topic_ID, item_id ORDER BY createdAt)
WHERE AttemptNo is null
```

But SQL does not like to do update table because it contains a derived field.

To test that my `LAG()` actually works, I used this code to test it:

```
SELECT *,
LAG(AttemptNo, 1) over (PARTITION BY user_ID, topic_ID, item_id ORDER BY createdAt) prevAttemptNo
FROM StartedRank
```

And it works, screenshot of result below:

[image]

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use cte like below

```
with cte as
(
SELECT *,
LAG(AttemptNo, 1) over (PARTITION BY user_ID, topic_ID, item_id ORDER BY createdAt) prevAttemptNo
FROM StartedRank
) update cte 
  set AttemptNo=prevAttemptNo
```

you can do this by join as welll

```
UPDATE A 
set AttemptNo=B.prevAttemptNo
FROM StartedRank A
JOIN (SELECT *,
    LAG(AttemptNo, 1) over (PARTITION BY user_ID, topic_ID, item_id ORDER BY createdAt) prevAttemptNo
    FROM StartedRank) B
    ON A.AttemptNo = B.AttemptNo
```

Comment: Hey - this is throwing this error: `Update or insert of view or function 'cte' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.`

Comment: @OdaySalim does it sql serber?

Comment: It is SQL Server